# What is Polygon MATIC crypto?

Tags: polygon, matic, staking

What is Polygon MATIC crypto and how does it work? Can you explain its features and benefits, as well as its use cases?

what are some potential risks and limitations of using the Polygon network and the MATIC cryptocurrency?